# Efficiently convert a long json array to the corresponding list

Tags: python

I could have a very long and variable json object like below (the length of the object could varry)

```
{
'1': 230,
'2':240,
'3':100,
'4':20,
...
'670000':100
}
```

I need to convert above JSON object to a simple unit8 array while keeping the order of elements without saving the indexes

```
[230,240,100,20,...,100]
```

well, I come up with below solution using genrators

```
def f(js):
...    for x in js:
...        yield js[x]
[x for x in f(js)]
```

But I wonder why if there is a more efficient solution as well?

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: No, it is json, I have put ... for summerization. In above sample JSON object, there 670000 elements.

Comment: It's not. JSON doesn't use `'`, it uses `"`.

Comment: That is fine...

Comment: may be use `ijson`

Comment: What's a "unit8 array"?

Comment: @superbrain Maybe they are using numpy?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Maybe. That's not what their solution does, though. And it's not "unit8" but "uint8". And it can't hold their value 340.

Comment: *efficient* and *optimized solution*  always sounds good, but does not answer, **what** has to be optimized: RAM consumption, speed, legibility? Depending on dynamics a tuple could be better than a list....

Comment: @superbrain, that was a typo and all elements are below 250

Comment: @Mahi some places you mentioned json array and some places json object. can you clarify is it json array or json object?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generator that steps through the items of a dictionary.

The `dict.values()` method will return a [*view object*](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__dict__#dict-views) that reflects the current object.

```py
def values_of(obj):
    for value in obj.values():
        yield value

data = {
    '1': 230,
    '2': 340,
    '3': 100,
    '4': 20,
    '670000': 100
}

print(list(values_of(data)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for an optimized solution. I have editted my questions.

Comment: @Mahi I included a generator.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Now you just made it inefficient.

Comment: @superbrain alright, I reverted it back to a `values` call.

Comment: Can you tell why you think your generator isn't worse than simply using `data.values()`?

Comment: note that before python 3.6, `values` order is not garanteed

Answer (score 0):

Simply turn it into python dictionary and append every value to the list like the following

```
data = {
'1': 230,
'2':340,
'3':100,
'4':20,
'670000':100
}
print([i for i in data.values()])
```

output

```
[230, 340, 100, 20, 100]
```

Comment: I have used generators and editted my question, I am looking for an optimized solution since I could have large arrays.